# Step back button for Commerece offsite payment method

Tags: commerce

I'm writing an offsite payment method for Drupal Commerce (I need that to interact with my bank API). The thing is that when I create a form to send to payment server via `PAYMENT_redirect_form` I have the only button - **SUBMIT** there. I want to add one more button there - smth like **GO A STEP BACK** to return to checkout state. So, i've created one more button, but it performs the same action as SUBMIT - goes to payment server... I think i'm missing smth very simple, but how can i make that one more button in payment submition form to perform a step back like those we have in checkout proccess?

Will be very thankful for your advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely you can't, because the form's action will be on a PayPal domain. So it'll always be submitted to them, and your site will never know about it.

The simplest solution would be to use a styled link instead of an input.

Comment: My point is that I want to have a possibility to cancel the payment before it is sibmitted to the payment server. Is it impossible?

Comment: No, not impossible; if you implement what I described above that's what will happen (unless I'm missing something)

Comment: I'm not sure that i understood your idea correctly, so will try to clearify my question a bit more. I'm creating a form with data which have to be sent to the offsite payment server via `PAYMENT_redirect_form` function. The form looks like a few fields with data plus submit button which sends all this to my bank server.

Comment: In my case 'offsite_autoredirect' option is disabled, so i need to click "SUBMIT" button (which i've created together with form) to perform data transfer. I have also created one more button called "CANCEL" in that form and my idea was to make that button perform a returning to chekout state (and i failed with that task).

Comment: From your answer I see that the form will be sent to the payment server anyway as well as it is said in its $form['#action']. So the thing is to create a markup element with a link inside instead of button? But if the order is on checkout_payment state, the cart is already empty, so we can't just return to checkout via simple url. And how can i make that link to perfom the step back action i need? Use hook_menu or i'm missing smth again?

Comment: I don't think there's a pretty way, so maybe just add a router item (/payment-cancel or something), point the link in the payment form to there, and in the page callback change the status of the current order to whatever makes sense, and forward onto to an appropriate page. The other option would be to intercept the action of the form and change to something internal, then re-jig that workflow to better suit what you're looking for. I'd go with the link approach personally, less work